# How to Protect my code and database from ISP Provider

Tags: web-services, web-hosting

I have completed a project here I used Html, CSS, Javascript, Jquery, Ajax and Php. I launch my project into a ISP Provider Company. But I worry about my project. I want that ISP Company or anyone can't access my code and Database. Is there any way that helps me to protect my code and database. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot secure code running on enemy hardware.
Period.

There is nothing you can do to stop an attacker with administrative privileges.

You shouldn't even rent space from an untrusted provider.  An attacker with hardware access can melt the case and add a logging device between the RAM and the CPU to see *all* data on the server.  (I don't know how practical that is)

If you don't trust your host, switch to a different host or run your own data-center.

Answer (score 0):

you can use some obfuscator like  http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=unmet_need&utm_campaign=smartassembly&gclid=CPq4uMC4nq0CFVBTfAod_x-umw

not sure How you save database?

Suggest use your own servers.