# How to protect mysql database from anyone

Tags: mysql, database-design, hosting, web-hosting

I have launched my project to a hosting company. But I am worried about how to protect my mysql database from the hosting company.

My question is how can I protect my database from the hosting company so they can't access my database / data.

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent your hosting company from viewing or interacting with data on their own machines? How about configuring your own server and hosting your project yourself?

Comment: my guess is that they probably don't care about your data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Protect my code and database from ISP Provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631167/how-to-protect-my-code-and-database-from-isp-provider)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a relevant rule of IT security:

"If a bad guy has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it's not your computer anymore."

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722487.aspx

Answer (score 4):

If you don't trust your hosting company, it's time to get a new one. There's little you can do to prevent someone with physical access to a server from getting at what's on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you will just have to trust them. There is no way to fully protect the database, because a hosting company has access to almost all levels of your application. They can event inject a code that would fetch all data in some layer of your application.

The hosting company is only one of the threats. You should think about XSS's, CSRF's, data sniffing at network level and so on...

Answer (score 0):

As all have answered there really is no way to protect your data from the hosting company.  They own the server therefore giving them access to all databases on it.

Depending on your data you could encrypt all of it but that's kind of overkill and not a practical solution unless your data is sensitive.  In that case I would recommend getting a server of your own and building it to support your needs.

You could check out rackspace and setup one of their servers but again if it's not physically in your possession they could potentially get on it and see what's there.  I think it's less likely as you would be setting up your own VM or server through them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is nothing we can do to prevent it from the hosting company. therefore  configuring your own server may be the only option.

Answer (score 0):

I whole heartedly endorse the general rule that Jay puts forward.

However, in certain environments it might be a good idea to take extra steps to ensure that your data is somewhat more protected given the rule that it really is someoneelses computer.

- Try to encrypt data that does not need to be acted up with public keys, and keep private keys off of the server. This is trivial to overcome if someone else can change the code and ensure that unencrypted copies are kept in parallel.
- So try to use stuff like Tripwire to ensure that your code has not been changed. Again tripwire can be reconfigured with physical access, so this is not fool proof, but it can work

Good luck, you are interested in a tackling an intractable problem, which are, of course, the most fun.

-FT